# How can we get the minimum and maximum dates of data in each indices in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How can we get the minimum and maximum dates of data in each indices in elastic search?

I was going through the documentation but not able to understand which API will help get the min and max dates of data in each indices in elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

I believe you could address that using the [`aggregation` feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/search-aggregations.html) of Elasticsearch.
You could use the [Min](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) and [Max](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) metric aggregation.

## Solution

This would look like that using the api:

```json
GET <The Index>/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "min": {
      "min": {
        "field": "<The date>"
      }
    },
    "max":{
      "max": {
        "field": "<The date>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result should look like so:

```json
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
...
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "min": {
      "value": 1660521603764,
      "value_as_string": "2022-08-15T00:00:03.764Z"
    },
    "max": {
      "value": 1665431791459,
      "value_as_string": "2022-10-10T19:56:31.459Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How can I convert this query into Java API code?
I had tried MaxAggregationBuilder and MinAggregationBuilder

Comment: I believe this is another question. Maybe open a new question with the Java code you wrote and explain where you have an issue. I am not a java dev _-_